# Layout distorts when keyboard is displayed android

Tags: android, layout

I have a relative layout that displays textviews, edittext, buttons. But whenever the keyboard is displayed, the layout is destroyed since the layout covers the entire screen. Here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/medhist"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:ems="8"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/medhistname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/medhistage"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="8"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/medhistweight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText01"
        android:ems="8"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/medhistheight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText02"
        android:ems="8"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/editBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="@string/editbtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editBtn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editBtn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/deletebtn" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/deleteBtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:lines="8"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minLines="6"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:text="@string/medhist"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you have any suggestions/solutions please do so, I'm new at android development. Thanks!

Comment: ellaborate `layout is destroyed`.

Comment: In your Activity tag manifest file, `<activity android:name="."
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">`or `adjustResize`.

Comment: Look at http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/

Comment: Destroyed = The some controls goes up to give way to the keyboard.